# Multiple forms: how to get form values from used form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I create dynamically a list of forms, but before submitting the user gets a jquery confirmation alert. I want to mention a formvalue in this confirmation text, but i can't found out how to do this

```
<form name="team_uit_laddercompetitie_zetten_frm" method="post" class="confirm_submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="team_uit_laddercompetitie_zetten" />
            <input type="hidden" name="teamID" value="<?php echo $aKlasse[$k]['teamnr'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="teamnaam" value="<?php echo teamnaam($aKlasse[$k]['teamnr']);?>" />
            <input type="submit" id="team_uit_laddercompetitie_zetten_submit" value="TEST: uit competitie zetten" />
        </form>
```

This is my jquery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".confirm_submit").click( function(){ 
var test = $this.form.teamnaam.value;
jConfirm('xWeet u zeker dat u het team:  uit de laddercompetietie wilt verwijderen?' + test, function(r) {
    if(r == true)
    {
        //$('#team_uit_laddercompetitie_zetten_frm').submit();
        alert('test');
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    });
return false;
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the value of the element with name `teamnaam` in the current form]

```
var test = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='teamnaam']").val();
```

Comment: many many mnay thanks! Spent hours on this one, got an answer here within e few seconds!!!! It works!!!!!

Comment: i did accept, but had to wait 9 minutes before it was possible to do so??